# JSON/Javascript object definition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Trying to identify the type of array, I have an multidimensional JSON array that i pull from a website, but its not using keypairs i am farmiliar with. The structure is as follows. I have only included 1 array item to show what it's doing.

```
"o": {
     "ah": ["id1", "12", "id2", "32", "id4", "4", "id5, "6"]
},
```

My searches on both JavaScript and JSON objects and strings always use a semi-colon *:*  to define the key and the value.

In the end I just want to loop through the multiple items and print them out.

To provide more clarification about the array structure:

```
{
    "outer": {
            "item1":[ {
                "c": {
                    "k": 26862, "n": "theName"
                },
                "o": {
                    "ah": ["id1", "0", "id2", "0", "id3", "0.98", "id4", "0.94", "id5", "5", "id6", "-0/0.5"], 
                    "ou": ["id7", "3.5", "id8", "3.5", "id9", "1.53", "id10", "0.55", "id11", "3.4", "id12"],
                    "1x2": ["id13", "1.20", "id14", "25.00", "id15", "4.80"]
                    },
                    "egn":""
                }
                ]
            },
            {
            "item1":[ {
                "c": {
                    "k": 26862, "n": "theName"
                },
                "o": {
                    "ah": ["bd1", "0", "bd2", "0", "bd3", "0.98", "bd4", "0.94", "bd5", "0.5", "bd6", "-0.5"], 
                "ou": ["bd7", "3.5", "bd8", "3.5", "bd9", "1.53", "bd10", "0.55", "bd11", "3.4", "bd12"],
                "1x2": ["bd13", "1.20", "bd14", "25.00", "bd15", "4.80"]
                },
                "egn":""
                }
                ]
    } 
}
```

If I wanted to bind an ID to a specific field e.g.  and it display the value of ID 1 in the array structure how would I do it without a keypair value, also if the array ID is not standardized so you can't loop through  like `var = "id"+ i` foreach element?

Comment: This *is* a key/value pair: the first key ("o") has an object as a value. The second key ("ah"), inside that object, has an array as a value.

Comment: What do you mean by _multidimensional_? Are there multiple arrays? Can you show a more complete structure with three or more?

Comment: Please educate yourself on what "JSON" is. It's a string representation used for exchanging data, such as between a server and a client. What you are showing has nothing to do with JSON. It's just a JavaScript object. Anyway, if your objective is to "loop through" the object, why does your title say "object definition"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`o` is an object, `ah` is an array which is a property of `o` object. You use `JSON.parse()` to convert `JSON` string to `javascript` object, then iterate over `o.ah` using `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```
// or however you obtain the JSON string
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); 
obj.o.ah.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Wait, why the `JSON.parse`? `o.ah` is an array, not a JSON string.

Comment: @qxz _"i have an multidimentional JSON array "_ If `JSON.parse()` is not necessary, `o.ah.forEach(function)` can be used

Comment: According to the JSON he posted, `o.ah` is an array... so the `JSON.parse` will cause an error.

Comment: @qxz _"According to the JSON he posted, o.ah is an array."_ Yes, though if `o` is `JSON`, `o` is a string, not a `javascript` object?

Comment: Then you would have to do `JSON.parse(o).ah.forEach`. If `o` is a string, `o.ah` is `undefined`, because strings don't have an `ah` property

Comment: @qxz Unclear from `JSON` snippet at Question. Could also be `JSON.parse(obj.o).ah.forEach()` _"I have only included 1 array item to show what its doing."_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122064/discussion-between-qxz-and-guest271314).